# Performance of my Objective-C vector math class is dominated by object creation

Tags: objective-c, performance

I need to perform a large amount of simple vector operations. Thus, for convenience, I've create a Vector class which holds a couple of useful methods, in which I sometimes need to allocate/init a new instance of Vector.

The problem is that, according to the Time Profiler (in Instruments), the time spent in allocation/initialization/deallocation is just huge, and the final computation time is 40x longer using my Vector class to perform the computation than doing it directly.

Below is a test program (main.m):

```
#define ImplementationType 1 // implementation switch

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "Vector.h"

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
  @autoreleasepool {

    CFTimeInterval startProcessingLoop = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent();
    Vector *initialVector = [[Vector alloc] init];
    Vector *addedVector = [Vector vectorWithValuesX:1 Y:2 Z:3];
    double scalarValue = 2.0;

    for (UInt ii = 0; ii < 100e6; ii++) {
#if ImplementationType == 1

      [initialVector addVector:[addedVector vectorByMultiplyingByScalar:scalarValue]];

#elif ImplementationType == 2

        initialVector->coords[0] += addedVector->coords[0]*scalarValue;
        initialVector->coords[1] += addedVector->coords[1]*scalarValue;
        initialVector->coords[2] += addedVector->coords[2]*scalarValue;
#endif
    }

    CFTimeInterval endProcessingLoop = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent();
    NSLog(@"Processing time: %gs", endProcessingLoop-startProcessingLoop);
    NSLog(@"Final values: %1.3e, %1.3e, %1.3e", initialVector->coords[0], initialVector->coords[1], initialVector->coords[2]);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Below is the Vector class interface:

```
@interface Vector : NSObject {

  @public double coords[3];

}

+ (Vector *)vectorWithValuesX:(double)x Y:(double)y Z:(double)z;

- (Vector *)vectorByMultiplyingByScalar:(double)scalar;
- (Vector *)addVector:(Vector *)vector;

@end
```

And this is the Vector class implementation:

```
#import "Vector.h"

@implementation Vector

+ (Vector *)vectorWithValuesX:(double)x Y:(double)y Z:(double)z {

  Vector *newVector = [[Vector alloc] init];

  newVector->coords[0] = x;
  newVector->coords[1] = y;
  newVector->coords[2] = z;

  return newVector;
}

- (Vector *)vectorByMultiplyingByScalar:(double)scalar {

  Vector *newVector = [[Vector alloc] init];

  newVector->coords[0] = coords[0]*scalar;
  newVector->coords[1] = coords[1]*scalar;
  newVector->coords[2] = coords[2]*scalar;

  return newVector;
}

- (Vector *)addVector:(Vector *)vector {

  coords[0] += vector->coords[0];
  coords[1] += vector->coords[1];
  coords[2] += vector->coords[2];

  return self;
}

@end
```

With `ImplementationType == 1`: Processing time: ~10s
With `ImplementationType == 2`: Processing time: ~0.25s

So, my question is: should I sacrifice convenience to increase speed or am I doing something wrong?

I've also tried the Accelerate framework without much success since most of the 'lost' time is spent in alloc/init/dealloc.

Comment: mhm hi and welcome to SO but I think this might be better suited for another EE site.. e.g. code review or so. This isn't really the qa style for this here

Comment: @Daij-Djan I think this is a reasonable question for SO — one can easily answer about the cost of object allocation vs. using stack-allocated structs and a functional style (returning a new object that is the result of a multiplication) vs. an imperative one (mutating the vector directly).

Comment: @ItaiFerber ok. I didn't vote anyway. Just a hint to the op. My fear is that this sparks very opinionated answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to remember that Objective-C *is* C. When you do arithmetic using `double`, `int` *et al* it is done the same way in Objective-C as in C, that is using value types and functions/operators.

You don't need to use Objective-C objects; which use reference types, dynamic allocation and method dispatch; for your own arithmetic types, you can do Follow the same pattern used for the standard types.

For example look at `NSDecimal`, a value type, and `NSDecimalNumber`, an object type based on it.

Your simple vector type can be defined along the lines of:

```
typedef struct { double x, y, z; } Vec;

NS_INLINE Vec vecAdd(Vec a, Vec b)
{
   return (Vec){a.x + b.x, a.y + b.y, a.z + b.z};
}

NS_INLINE Vec vecMulByScalar(Vec a, double s)
{
   return (Vec){a.x * s, a.y * s, a.z * s};
}
```

and used as:

```
Vec initialVector = {0, 0, 0};
Vec addedVector = {1, 2, 3};
double scalarValue = 2.0;

for (UInt ii = 0; ii < 100e6; ii++)
{
    initialVector = vecAdd(initialVector, vecMulByScalar(addedVector, scalarValue));
}
```

For comparison on my test machine your code runs at ~9.5s and ~0.24s respectively. The above `Vec` runs at ~0.08s (with or without the `NS_INLINE`, the optimiser is good enough to inline in this example).

Note: The above code uses pass-by-value for its functions. Looking at `NSDecimal` you will will see its uses pass-by-reference. (Both of course use value semantics.) This is primarily a matter of style and also the size of the type - pass-by-reference might be more suitable for large value types (though here `Vec` is 4 bytes larger then `NSDecimal`).

HTH

Comment: Thank you very much !! I even prefer this solution to C++ classes in my project. I've just implemented it and it is as fast as the C++ solution. Thanks again !

Answer (score 0):

I think you really don't need to make these allocations, at least in the particular use case shown in your code sample.

Instead of creating a new instance of `Vector` in `vectorByMultiplyingByScalar:`, you can modify the *existing* instance in-place:

```
- (void)multiplyByScalar:(double)scalar {

//note that you don't have to use self->coords to access instance variables
  coords[0] = coords[0]*scalar;
  coords[1] = coords[1]*scalar;
  coords[2] = coords[2]*scalar;
}
```

This can still be a bit slower than implementation 1, because of the cost of dynamic method dispatch in Objetive-C. But it should be noticeably faster than implementation 2 because there are no allocations. 
If you really do millions of calculations, the best solution would be to drop Objective-C altogether for the performance-critical code and use C/C++ (or even Swift).

Your `vectorByMultiplyingByScalar:` method might still be useful in some cases, when you want to use immutable "defensive copies" of existing objects. For example, you can reference one `Vector` instance in many places (or even in many threads) and you want to make the change only in the local context.

But this is not the best approach when you are doing lots of calculations inside a simple loop.

You can read more about "Object Mutability" in Foundation classes [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/CocoaEncyclopedia/ObjectMutability/ObjectMutability.html).

Comment: Thank you Michal. That's the response I feared. I just tried mixing Objective-C and C++ (C++ for the Vector class), and the processing time is 0.08s !! (inlining the vector contructor and operators overloading)